# Is Maven necessary for a Java application that uses MongoDB to store data?

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am making a Java webapp that uses MongoDB to store data. Is it necessary to have Maven for this? Whatever example and tutorial I saw on Internet, contains Maven. Is it not possible to do it without Maven?

Comment: What do you think Maven is? When you looked it up on Google or elsewhere on Stack Overflow, what did you find out about it?

Comment: Sure it's possible; you can replace maven with a different dependency manager, or just do everything manually.  Why do you want to do this, though?

Comment: @Pillar i know its a dependancy manager. i have never worked with this and neither with mongodb. so i was confused.

Comment: @azurefrog my company is switching from oracle to mongodb. so, i have to learn this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is a `Dependency manager`. Maven has no link with MongoDB. Yes, you can use maven in your project to manage dependencies. MongoDB is a database. You can create application without using `MAVEN`.